# Разбивка компонентов Reactjs по файлам

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Здравствуйте! Скажите, как можно разбить компоненты react по файлам и организовать их подгрузку?

Comment: Разбить - руками, а вместо подгрузки стоит собирать приложение, используя webpack или browserify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если использовать синтаксис ES6, то файле, который содержит компонент (`hello-world.jsx`), можно написать так:

```
import React from 'react';

export default React.createClass({
    render() {
       return <div>Hello, World!</div>;
    }
});
```

А в основном файле (`app.jsx`), где вы будете использовать данный компонент, так:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import HelloWorld from './hello-world.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld />, document.getElementById('hello'));
```

Собрать это можно командой:
`browserify -t babelify app.jsx -o build/bundle.js`